# Passing data from router to Jade template

Tags: meteor, pug, iron-router

I have Jade template:

```
template(name="mainLayout")
  h1= data
  h3 Meteor.js Example
```

When I try to pass data to template in router:

```coffee
Router.route "/", () ->
  @render "index", data: "My Awesome Page"
```

This is not working. How to pass the data into template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data` passed in the router is `this` in the jade.

So instead of:

```
h1= data
```

Try:

```
h1= this
```

If you want to pass more data, you can do like this:

```
template(name="mainLayout")
  h1= this.data1
  h2= this.data2
  // or shorted, just ignore the this.
  h1= data1
  h2= data2
  h3 Meteor.js Example

Router.route "/", () ->
  @render "index", data: { data1: "My Awesome Page", data2: "Foobar" }
```

Comment: It returns `[object Object]`, not the string.

Comment: if you do render "index", the data will be accessible in index template, not mainLayout. did you try to display `this` in index template?

Comment: I tried to display `this` in template: it shows `[object Object]`. I changed `@render "index"...` to `@render "mainLayout"...`, but it still not working. I think that the `Router` does not work directly with Jade.

Comment: I use iron:router + jade everyday without any problem so the it's not the problem.

Comment: it's work here with html http://meteorpad.com/pad/TATK27wg98kBxAEhw/Leaderboard Try to replace h1= this by h1 {{this}} just to see

Comment: Okay. Thanks for your help. I need to learn in more detail how the `Router` works.

Comment: you can start with copying the meteorpad i gave you and then change the .js in .coffee and if it still work change the .html in .jade so you ll see what s wrong